# The numbers I enter are not being sorted in ascending order and the triangle seems to always be valid no matter what the numbers are. Any suggestions?

Tags: java

The numbers I enter are not being sorted in ascending order and the triangle seems to always be valid no matter what the numbers are. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/** An exercise of using methods */

public class MethodExercise {

/**main method */
//Group A fill in the blanks for this method
public static void main (String[] args) {
  double num1, num2, num3, avg, max;


  //Get input for the three numbers
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");      
  num1 = kb.nextDouble();

  System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
  num2 = kb.nextDouble();

  System.out.print("Enter the third number: ");
  num3 = kb.nextDouble();



  //Call calcAverage method 
  avg=(num1+num2+num3)/3;

 //Output the result
  System.out.println("The average of the three numbers is " + avg);

  //Call findMax method
  double[] myList = {num1,num2,num3};
  myList = new double[3];
  myList[0] = num1;
  myList[1] = num2;
  myList[2] = num3;
  max = myList[0];
  for (int i = 1;i<myList.length;i++){
  if(myList[i]>max)
    max = myList[i];
  }

  //Output max
  System.out.println("The maximum number of the three numbers is " + max);

  //Call sort method
 System.out.println("The sorted int array is:");
 for (double number : myList) {
System.out.println("Number = " + number);

   }

  //Call isValidTriangle method
   boolean isTriangle = true||false; 

    if ((num1+num2>num3)||(num1+num3>num2)||(num2+num3>num1)){
        isTriangle = true;
     }

  if (isTriangle == true){
    System.out.println("It is a valid triangle");
    }
  else 
    System.out.println("It is not a valid triangle");

  } //end main

  /**Method calcAverage: calculates and returns the average of the three numbers*/

 /**Method findMax: finds and returns the maximum number among the three numbers*/

 /**Method sort: sorts and displays the three numbers in increasing order*/

 /**Method isValidTriangle: determines if the three numbers (representing three edges)
      can form a valid triangle*/

  } //end class
```

Comment: This needs a lot more detail. Your post seems to assume we know exactly what you're trying to do or what your assignment is.

Comment: I don't see the sort method... Just you printing out values? and why? `boolean isTriangle = true||false;`

Comment: Hint: Your triangle check is true if one of the conditions is true ...

Comment: The only time your triangle is invalid is when all numbers are 0. As Sinclair stated there is no condition which would actually return the triangle as invalid. Can you please state may be not in the code but in words when do you want to return this as invalid for e.g "when all numbers are 0" or "when num1 and num 3 are ".

Comment: As far as sorting is concerned add this part before your comment"Call sort method"   Arrays.sort(myList); as per your code you don't have anything that actually sorts the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you are supposed to put the code into their own methods, but I'll leave that to you... As for your sorting method, it needs some work. Here's what I have for that...

```
double[] myList = {num1,num2,num3};
double temp;
for (int i = 1; i < myList.length; i++) {
   for(int j = i ; j > 0 ; j--){
      if(myList[j] < myList[j-1]){
         temp = myList[j];
         myList[j] = myList[j-1];
         myList[j-1] = temp;
      }
   }
}

//Output max
System.out.println("The maximum number of the three numbers is " + myList[2]);
```

Also, this here is redundant.

```
double[] myList = {num1,num2,num3};
myList = new double[3];
myList[0] = num1;
myList[1] = num2;
myList[2] = num3;
```

In the first line you assign the values in the array, and then you empty the array with `myList = new double[3];` and then fill the array again.

As for testing to see if a triangle is possible your 'isTriangle' variable starts true (because true || false is true) and has no way to become false. Also, your test is fundamentally flawed. Think about it. A triangle with sides 1, 2, and 100 is DEFINITELY NOT a triangle; your method says it is because

```
1 + 2 > 100 is false
1 + 100 > 2 true
2 + 100 > 1 true

false || true || true is true
```

It should go about it like this. Perform each of those calculations and if ANY of them are FALSE, then it can't be a triangle...

```
boolean isTriangle = true;
if (!(num1+num2>num3)||!(num1+num3>num2)||!(num2+num3>num1)){
   isTriangle = false;
}

if (isTriangle == true){
   System.out.println("It is a valid triangle");
} else {
   System.out.println("It is not a valid triangle");
}
```

Well, I think that's about it. Although you should put each of those groups of code in their own method.

Comment: Makes much more sense now. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting the `isTriangle` to `false`. The below statement will set it to `true` and then you are again setting it `true` from where you are performing the comparison.

```
/* This will set isTriangle to true because (TRUE OR FALSE) always evaluates to TRUE */
boolean isTriangle = true||false;
```

You should do this instead:

```
boolean isTriangle = false;
```